# how to write logic of draw in Tac tac toe, kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, tic-tac-toe

I am making tic tac toe in android studio on kotlin, I am new at this, I complete everything but i want to make that if none of combinations matchs then write on screen that it's draw but i cant write some logic or i missed something:

this is draw function code:

```
 private fun draw() {

    if (!firstPLayer.contains(1) && !firstPLayer.contains(2) && !firstPLayer.contains(3)) {
        resultView.text = "Draw!"
    }
    if (!secondPLayer.contains(1) && !secondPLayer.contains(2) && !secondPLayer.contains(3)) {
        resultView.text = "Draw!"
    }

    if (!firstPLayer.contains(4) && !firstPLayer.contains(5) && !firstPLayer.contains(6)) {
        resultView.text = "Draw!"
    }
    if (!secondPLayer.contains(4) && !secondPLayer.contains(5) && !secondPLayer.contains(6)) {
        resultView.text = "Draw!"
    }

    if (!firstPLayer.contains(7) && !firstPLayer.contains(8) && !firstPLayer.contains(9)) {
        resultView.text = "Draw!"
    }
    if (!secondPLayer.contains(7) && !secondPLayer.contains(8) && !secondPLayer.contains(9)) {
        resultView.text = "Draw!"
    }

    if (!firstPLayer.contains(1) && !firstPLayer.contains(4) && !firstPLayer.contains(7)) {
        resultView.text = "Draw!"
    }
    if (!secondPLayer.contains(1) && !secondPLayer.contains(4) && !secondPLayer.contains(7)) {
        resultView.text = "Draw!"
    }

    if (!firstPLayer.contains(2) && !firstPLayer.contains(5) && !firstPLayer.contains(8)) {
        resultView.text = "Draw!"
    }
    if (!secondPLayer.contains(2) && !secondPLayer.contains(5) && !secondPLayer.contains(8)) {
        resultView.text = "Draw!"
    }

    if (!firstPLayer.contains(3) && !firstPLayer.contains(6) && !firstPLayer.contains(9)) {
        resultView.text = "Draw!"
    }
    if (!secondPLayer.contains(3) && !secondPLayer.contains(6) && !secondPLayer.contains(9)) {
        resultView.text = "Draw!"
    }

    if (!firstPLayer.contains(1) && !firstPLayer.contains(5) && !firstPLayer.contains(9)) {
        resultView.text = "Draw!"
    }
    if (!secondPLayer.contains(1) && !secondPLayer.contains(5) && !secondPLayer.contains(9)) {
        resultView.text = "Draw!"
    }

    if (!firstPLayer.contains(3) && !firstPLayer.contains(5) && !firstPLayer.contains(7)) {
        resultView.text = "Draw!"
    }
    if (!secondPLayer.contains(3) && !secondPLayer.contains(5) && !secondPLayer.contains(7)) {
        resultView.text = "Draw!"
    }

}
```

so, I am saying that if there isn't this combinations of number in lists, write "draw" in resultView
but it shows draw on first click on any button.
why?

Comment: Well you would want all those if's to be a when statement, if-else, or a bunch of or statements in a single if... the face that you have them all as their own if statements will cause issues - that said there is far easier ways to achieve what your going for - if you find yourself repeating similar code this much theres proably a better way!

Comment: i tried to write this if-s in if-else function but it didn't work.

Comment: To paraphrase the logic: "if X is not a bear, then X is not an animal and also if X is not a horse, then X is not an animal". If we try with X=horse, it will claim that that's not an animal, because it's not a bear at the same time. To put it another way, the logic doesn't work, toss it and start over.

Comment: And aren't you tired of writing all of that out? Haven't you wondered if maybe there is some other way? One involving loops perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following assumes that `playerOne` and `playerTwo` are `List<Int>`s containing which of the nine squares from 1-9 the players have placed marks in.

Any time you see that you're copy-pasting code more than once (like `resultView.text = "Draw!"` and all the similar-looking if statements), you should rethink the design to simplify it.

I would create a collection of all possible win conditions:

```
private val winConditions = listOf(
    listOf(1, 2, 3),
    listOf(4, 5, 6),
    listOf(7, 8, 9),
    listOf(1, 4, 7),
    listOf(2, 5, 8),
    listOf(3, 6, 9),
    listOf(1, 5, 9),
    listOf(3, 5, 7),
)
```

Then each time a player makes a mark, you can check if either player won. If neither player won and nine moves have been made, the game is a draw.

```
// In a function called right after a player makes a move:
when {
    winConditions.any { playerOne.containsAll(it) } -> showPlayerOneWins()
    winConditions.any { playerTwo.containsAll(it) } -> showPlayerTwoWins()
    playerOne.size + playerTwo.size == 9 -> showGameIsDraw()
    else -> startNextPlayerTurn()
}
```

To get more fancy, you could have it only check the player who just made a move. That might make sense if it was a complicated algorithm to determine the winner, but Tic Tac Toe is trivial so I think it's just simpler to simply check them both so you can use the same code without extra parameters.

Comment: thank you! I will try your method, its really complicated but I will practice.

Answer (score 1):

There are better ways to do what you're doing, like in Tenfour04's answer, but your basic approach is fine! Hard work, but it works. It's just the logic doesn't exactly fit what you're trying to do.

So, I'm assuming `firstPlayer` is a list (or some other collection) that holds the square numbers that *player1* has marked with their X or O, and the same thing for `secondPlayer`. And I think what you're doing is checking all the winning combinations, and if nobody has any of those, the game is a draw. Is that right?

---

Your first problem is what you're running into - if you click a button, and `draw()` gets called, it tells you it's a draw. How come? Well, think about what you're doing - you're checking if anyone has a win condition, which they don't, because it's the start of the game. So the result is *"draw!"*

So really, you can't call `draw()` at any time, because the game has four possible states: *player1 win*, *player2 win*, *draw* (which are all finished states) and *in progress*, which basically means none of the end states have been reached yet. You're checking for the win states, but assuming that if they don't match, you must be in the *draw* state.

So, you'll either need to call `draw()` when you **know** one of those end states has been reached (which you can't really know without checking), or you'll need to explicitly check for a draw state along with the win state checks. (One thing you could think about, is whether all the squares have been filled.)

---

The other thing is that your logic doesn't really handle the win states properly. Imagine *player 2* has the top line filled. The first `if` confirms *player 1* **doesn't have** that line. They don't of course, so it prints *"draw!"* If you think about it, at most **one** of those win states can match, so either every other check is going to pass and set the result text to *"draw!"*

Typically the way you'd handle this kind of thing is to have a boolean flag set to a default, and set it when a check "trips the alarm" if you like. You only set it one way, so once it flips from the default to being set, another check won't flip it back

```
// assuming a draw until we know otherwise
var draw = true

// checking if player 1 has WON
if (firstPLayer.contains(1) && firstPLayer.contains(2) && firstPLayer.contains(3)) {
    // when we know someone's won, we can say things like it's not a draw, maybe record who won
    draw = false
}
...

// set the text either way, ensuring it always displays the correct thing
resultView.text = if (draw) "draw!" else ""
```

notice I swapped the `if` condition to check if *player 1* has **won**, not if they've **not won**. This way we're looking for the specific condition where we can set the flag. It's easier to handle "was this condition was ever met" than "were any of these conditions never met".

It depends on the person, but sometimes it's easier to work these things out on paper - write down the questions you need to ask, to check if someone's won, someone's lost, is it a draw or is the game still going. Have a think about it!

Comment: thank you for this answer! I am very greatful for your labor. I already fix that logic but really man, thank you.